# LNK2020 when making a variable static

Tags: c++-cli

I use C++/CLI to link between a .NET application and a dynamically loaded C dll.

So far all access to the DLL is instance based.

The class

```
namespace NxCore {
    public class NativeConnector {
```

has variable for various references to methods:

```
        HMODULE hLib;
        NxCoreProcessTape pfNxProcessTape;
        NxCorePriceToDouble pfNxPriceToDouble;
        NxCoreGetDefinedString pfNxCoreGetDefinedString;
        NxCoreGetSymbolAtom32 pfNxGetSymbolAtom32;
        NxCoreStateGetMMQuotes pfNxStateGetMmQuotes;
```

I load those in a connect method:

```
    hLib = ::LoadLibrary("NxCoreAPI.dll");
```

then

```
    pfNxProcessTape = (NxCoreProcessTape)::GetProcAddress(hLib, cszNxCoreProcessTape);
    pfNxPriceToDouble = (NxCorePriceToDouble)::GetProcAddress(hLib, cszNxCorePriceToDouble);
    pfNxCoreGetDefinedString = (NxCoreGetDefinedString)::GetProcAddress(hLib, cszNxCoreGetDefinedString);
```

etc.

Now I need to move that to multi instances, so I want to load on first connect, unload on last disconnect. This means the variables must go static.

In C# I would just make them static. I try one:

```
    static HMODULE hLib;
```

and linking fails:

4>NativeConnector.obj : error LNK2020: unresolved token (0A00006D) "private: static struct HINSTANCE__ * NxCore::NativeConnector::hLib" (?hLib@NativeConnector@NxCore@Connectivity@Tradex@@0PAUHINSTANCE__@@A)

Anyone an idea how to fix it? The header file is used on the .cpp file, so - it should not have different definitions.

Anyone can tell he how to fix that issue? As i said - I want to move the variables to be static and then use "usage counting" myself to make sure that I release on last disconnect.

Comment: Did you *define* the static member?

Comment: As I said - I added a "static" in the header file. Is there any other place I have to define them? It works if the header file (class definition) does not ahve them as static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the code shown I'm not exactly clear on whether the problem occurs in a ref class (.NET class) or a native C++ class.

Here is my advice assuming a native type: You need to define the declared member

- header

  ```
  struct X
  {
      static int s_data;
  };
  ```
- cpp source:

  ```
  #include "X.h"

  int X::s_data /* = 42 */;
  ```

For ref types I'd actually expect the same semantics for static as with C#